# Windows Share Meltdown, Unexplainable

Tags: windows, file-sharing, anti-virus

I am having precisely the exact symptoms on my server as is described [in this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961293).

This includes statements that

```
the specified network name is no longer available
```

and

```
RPC Server is too busy to process the request
```

However,

The prescribed handling in the article solely points to Symantec Endpoint Protection, and.... I don't have Symantec Endpoint Protection!!

This problem is totally destroying my server and creating hours of blood, sweat and tears, and I cannot find a solution to it.

This problem had been creeping up on client computers as well with no traceable source, so I am suspicious that some virus is not reproducing the exact same effect that Symantec managed to create, however despite virus scans by multiple vendors I cannot find anything.

Help...

#### More Revelations...

After hard booting the server due to total unresponsiveness several times, I have picked up the pattern that the server seems fine for up to an hour or two, and then starts freaking out.

I am trying to nail the event logs at the time it freaks out, but haven't found anything yet and am again waiting for the next bout of craziness.

Comment: What steps have you already taken to resolve the issue? E.g. Have you tried restarting the Remote Procedure Call service, or the whole server for that matter? RPC errors can sometimes indicate a problem with name resolution. Are you able to access services / shares on the server via IP address and not names?

Comment: Also - please have a look through the event viewer and list the ID's for any system errors that look relevant.

Comment: Check the DNS suffix of the remote machine (the machine which has the share).  So if server is "servername", do an nslookup "servername" and see what comes back.  Do the nslookup without the FQ domain name.  I've seen this happen when the domain is incorrect or not in the hosts file.   I've also seen when a user which runs the application using the share doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: @blacklight, yes, I have had to hard-reboot the server 4 times. When the problem hits, you can't log in, log out, shut down, anything. just times out. After rebooting, server is fine for an hour or two then *freaks out*.

Comment: @Schrute, thanks. The connection problems come up even when trying direct IP addresses and bypassing DNS, and there hasn't been any change that would have edited host files or DNS addresses.

Comment: @blacklight, I did check event viewer, seems the `svchost - iphlpsvc` executable crashed several times, which might be related, otherwise some `svr` errors relating to tcp ip... haven't nailed anything on those yet.

Comment: If you unplug the network connection when it seems to be locked up, does the server console return to normal?